Is this proof correct? (Undergraduate Real Analysis)

Problem. Let $(x_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of real numbers and let $x$ be in $\mathbb{R}$. Prove that if $\lim_{n \to +\infty} x_n = x$ and if $x > 0$, then there exists a natural number $M$ such that $x_n > 0$ for all $n \geq M$.

Proof: Suppose $\lim_{n \to +\infty} x_n = x$ and $x > 0$. Then for all $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a natural number $K$ such that $n \geq K$ implies that $|x_n – x| < \epsilon$. Let a natural number $M$ be given such that $x_n > 0$ for all $n \geq M$. Notice that if $x_n > 0$, then $|x_n| > 0$. But
$$|x_n| = |x_n-x+x| \leq |x_n -x|+|x| < \epsilon + |x| = \epsilon + x. $$
So, $|x_n| - x < \epsilon$. But since $x_n, x  > 0$, We have that
$$ |x_n| - x = |x_n-x| < \epsilon. $$
Sorry the format is so awful, but $x_n$ is a sequence.

Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Here is a formatting tutorial

Just pick $\varepsilon = x$; then you are guaranteed some $N_\varepsilon \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ such that $|x_n - x| < \varepsilon = x \implies 0 < x_n < 2 x$ for each $n \ge N_\varepsilon$, and you are done.

You have asked in the title if "this proof [is] correct" but the problem should be stated fully in the body of the Question.  And it isn't.  You simply present a proposition and follow with a (proclaimed) "proof".  It makes it a little harder for Readers to work out what you wanted to ask.   Is something in the "proof" unclear to you?  Or is something dubious?  Many Readers will be dissuaded from responding if it seems you are just looking for a pat on the back.  Please clarify why you want "solution verification" on this proof attempt.  Sometimes a proof idea is correct but could be improved.

Well yes I am kind of looking for a pat on the back. Basically the statement just says that if the limit of a sequence is positive, then at some index, the terms must be positive. I just have a weak background in proof writing and so I thought I would use this website to find much smarter people to review it. The thing that some people have said is that I have to find M by proof, but I thought that assuming one exists, and then arriving at a correct deduction, then it was satisfactory.

Your proof is flawed. The $M$ you mentioned must be found with proof and cannot be given as you are trying to show $x_n > 0$ for $n \ge M$. Here is my version of it. Let $\epsilon = \dfrac{x}{2} > 0$, then there exists a natural number $M$ such that if $n \ge M$ then $|x_n - x| < \epsilon = \dfrac{x}{2}$. But $x - x_n \le |x_n - x|$. So: $x-x_n < \dfrac{x}{2}$, and then $x_n > x - \dfrac{x}{2} = \dfrac{x}{2} > 0$. We're done.
